# Iphone local storage clears automatically

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, worklight-studio

Using Worklight version 6.1.0.2-201603141430

Its a hybrid app.

IOS version: 10.1.1
Model: MG472HN/A

Its production issue. Recently one user reported our app data got cleared on his iphone. It happened him 3 times. Which making user to re-register him again and again. Unable to check logs because as not sure at what time it going clear.

We are storing a bit of information in local storage of device by using localStorage.setItem("isRegistered", status);

Doubted whether that Iphone running out of space. But seen still 1.8 GB storage space is available on device.

Answer (score 0):

First, this should be a PMR for IBM Support and not a question in Stack Overflow - open a PMR.

Second, note that you're using Worklight 6.1, and in this release IBM does not support iOS 10. See here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/06/05/support-plan-for-ios-10/